# Retain only 3 highest positive and negative records in a table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am new to databases and postgres as such.
I have a table called names which has 2 columns name and value which gets updated every x seconds with new name value pairs. My requirement is to retain only 3 positive and 3 negative values at any point of time and delete the rest of the rows during each table update.
I use the following query to delete the old rows and retain the 3 positive and 3 negative values ordered by value.

```
delete from names
using (select  *,
row_number() over (partition by value > 0, value < 0 order by value desc) as rn
from names ) w
where w.rn >=3
```

I am skeptical to use a conditional like value > 0 in a partition statement. Is this approach correct?

For example,

A table like this prior to delete :

```
name  | value 
--------------
test  |  10 
test1 |  11
test1 |  12
test1 |  13
test4 |  -1
test4 |  -2
```

My table after delete should look like :

```
name  | value 
--------------
test1 |  13
test1 |  12
test1 |  11
test4 |  -1 
test4 |  -2
```

Comment: can you please share an example of the output? Not able to understand the  statement to retain only 3 rows of values greater than and less than 0 at any point of time

Comment: What's `txid` in your query?

Comment: @Dassum and @ Laurenz Albe , I have updated the statement to be more clear. My table should contain 3 rows with positive and negative values after my table update.

Comment: Why do you need to delete the other rows?

Comment: If there were more than 3 negative values, which should be kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a6e4aeb863c6c68f2ae73bad4dd59c22)

This works generally as expected: `value > 0` clusters the values into all numbers > 0 and all numbers <= 0. The `ORDER BY value` orders these two groups as expected well.

So, the only thing, I would change:

```
row_number() over (partition by value >= 0 order by value desc)
```

1. remove: `, value < 0` (Because: Why should you group the positive values into negative and other? You don't have any negative numbers in your positive group and vice versa.)
2. change: `value > 0` to `value >= 0` to ignore the `0` as long as possible

---

For deleting: If you want to keep the top 3 values of each direction:

1. you should change `w.rn >= 3` into `w.rn > 3` (it keeps the 3rd element as well)
2. you need to connect the subquery with the table records. In real cases you should use id columns for that. In your example you could take the value column: `where n.value = w.value AND w.rn > 3`

So, finally:

```
delete from names n
using (select  *,
row_number() over (partition by value >= 0 order by value desc) as rn
from names ) w
where n.value = w.value AND w.rn > 3
```

Comment: After reading your problem again, I see something missing for the delete operation. Added this

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a hard requirement to delete the other rows, you could instead select only the rows you're interested in:

```
WITH largest AS (
  SELECT name, value
    FROM names
   ORDER BY value DESC
   LIMIT 3),
     smallest AS (
  SELECT name, value
    FROM names
   ORDER BY value ASC
   LIMIT 3)
SELECT * FROM largest
UNION
SELECT * FROM smallest
ORDER BY value DESC
```

Comment: I would need to delete the remaining rows.